# Count number of files in folders

Tags: cmd, count, directory, subdirectory

I'm currently at work and I was wondering if there is any way to show number of files in each folder(/subfolder). Would make my work a lot easier

If im using CMD and want to count all folders of files within each folder, i want it to look like something like this

C:\Ùsers\Me\Documents:

Folder1 - 10 files

Folder2 - 3 files

--> FolderInsideFolder2: 2 files

Folder 3: 9 files

Have searched for it but cant seem to find an answer to this. It is even possible? Thanks in advance

Comment: This post might be helpful https://rodolfovaraujo.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/count-number-of-files-using-command-prompt/

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "dirname="
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims= " %%a IN (
  'dir /s "%sourcedir%\*" ^|findstr /i "\ file(s)"'
 ) DO (
  IF DEFINED DIRNAME (ECHO !dirname! %%a files&SET "dirname=") ELSE (SET "dirname=%%c")
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

This code would produce incorrect directorynames for directorynames containing some special characters (like `!`) but should be fine for alphamerics.

It would no doubt fail if there happens to be a filename containing the string `file(s)`.

As a quick-and-dirty version, you could try

```
'dir /s "%sourcedir%\*" |findstr /i "\ file(s)"'
```

where `%sourcedir%`is replaced by the name of your target directory.

---

Following JosefZ comments: revision 1 to defeat problem with directorynames containing the string "file(s)" by rejecting `dir /s` lines containing <kbd><</kbd>

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "dirname="
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims= " %%a IN (
  'dir /s "%sourcedir%\*" ^|find /v "<" ^|findstr /i "\ file(s)"'
 ) DO (
  IF DEFINED DIRNAME (ECHO !dirname! %%a files&SET "dirname=") ELSE (SET "dirname=%%c")
)
GOTO :EOF
```

And revision 2 to ensure that the **original** line picked to report the number of files starts with two spaces (a line reporting a filename matching "*file(s)*" would start "nn" or " n" where n is a numeric)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=."
SET "dirname="
FOR /f "delims=" %%A IN (
  'dir /s "%sourcedir%\*" ^|find /v "<" ^|findstr /i "\ file(s)"'
 ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2,*delims= " %%a IN ("%%A") DO (
   IF DEFINED DIRNAME (
    SET "line=%%A"
    IF "!line:~0,2!"=="  " (ECHO !dirname! %%a files&SET "dirname=")
   ) ELSE (SET "dirname=%%c")
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Well done, apart from exclamation mark(s) in folder name. However will fail if there exist a folder or file named `file(s)`. Change `(ECHO !dirname! %%a files&SET "dirname=")` to `(If /I "%%b"=="file(s)" (ECHO !dirname! %%a files&SET "dirname="))`. Out of curiosity: why does not show empty folders, i.e. `0 File(s)`?

Comment: @JosefZ : FIxed using a slightly different method. Works with empty directories for me. You have the skills to resolve the glitch. I have confidence.